# How to use exists and $p in Drools?

Tags: java, drools

Is there any way to use `exists` with a variable `$p` to refer it then in the RHS of a *Drools* rule?

I want to check if exists an object in my Working Memory, with `exists` to avoid the rule match more than once, but I want to save the reference to the object matched so I could use it in the RHS.

Example what I want:

```
rule "Print a Person"

when
    exists ($p: Person()) <- This fails in drools
then
    System.out.println("Hello "+$p.getName());
end
```

Any idea or alternative to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `exists`, just use the code as shown below - the rule will be activated only if there is a fact of type `Person()`.  The rule will fire once for each of the `Person()` fact if working memory has more than one fact of type `Person()`

```
rule "Print a Person"

when
    $p: Person()
then
    System.out.println("Hello "+$p.getName());
end
```

If you really want to process only one person even if there are multiple facts of type `Person` are present in working memory, you can create a new class `Processed` to be used as a fact, and insert an instance of it as fact in `then` clause.  Something like below:

```
rule "Print a Person"

when
    $p: Person()
    not Processed()
then
    System.out.println("Hello "+$p.getName());
    insert(new Processed());
end
```

PS: I have not tested the above code, but have used such codes in my projects.  It illustrates how to accomplish what you are trying to do

Comment: The second proposal isn't going to work as advertised: it'll still fire for each Person fact unless you manage to insert just one with processed == false.

Comment: @laune Yeah, you are right.  Thanks - will remove it

Answer (score 0):

For completeness' sake here's another possibility which doesn't require a special field or the insertion of a Processed fact - but it requires that you have a *unique ordered* attribute, such as a personal identification number (social security number) or similar.

```
rule "fire for one Person"
when
    $p: Person( $id: id )
    not Person( id > $id )
then
    ...
end
```

This will pick the Person with the smallest id.